# read binary file and store into hive using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

Would like to read a binary file from local disk
and write into HVE as key value - blob using spark.
Format is as below :
   table XXX
      MyKey ---> BinaryBlob

By looking at other answer, I found this to read but this is not clear how to insert into HIVE.

```
sc.binaryFiles("file:///path/to/local/file") 


http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2756471&seqNum=4
```